# How can I set Sourcetree to use ssh paths by default when cloning a remote repo?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

When I clone a remote repository in SourceTree from github, it automatically uses an HTTP path. This means that any time I want to push/pull, I need to enter a password. I would like to use the ssh path (i.e. `git@github.com:username/repo.git`).

I noticed that there is an option to select "Protocol" when entering the remote account information. However, changing the value (and even recreating the account) appears to have no affect.

[image]

Please advise on the best way to force SourceTree to use the ssh path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the SSH-URL (i.e. git@github.com:username/repo.git).

Go to the Bitbucket application:
Click on "New Repository" -> "Clone from URL" -> Enter the SSH-URL, choose Destination Path and Name.
I think its the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is the way to do it. What is the point of being able to select "Protocol" in the above dialog?

Comment: Your Screenshot is from "Settings" > "Edit Account..." right? 
I quess you can choose your prefer protocol there for the Account. But I had to type in the SSH-URL after clicking on "Remote" and "Clone". 
Correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: For some reason, changing the "protocol" has no effect. But, manually entering the correct url works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is useful but on Windows to default to SSH for remote clone from with-in SourceTree:
[Default to SSH for remote clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjPlJ.png)