# Git submodule public key permissions error

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have two repositories hosted in Bitbucket - I have an access key setup that I can use to clone each project individually. Repository A has repository B as a submodule.

On Windows... after successfully cloning the repo A, `git submodule update --init` fails due to the following:

```
Cloning into 'C:/Path/to/submodules/B'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and that the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:org/B.git' into submodule path 'C:/path/to/submodules/B' failed
Failed to clone 'submodules/B'. Retry scheduled
```

The `.gitmodules` setup is as the following

```
[submodule "submodules/B"]
    path = submodules/B
    url = git@bitbucket.org:org/B.git
...
```

If I take that URL as specified in the `.gitmodules` and clone that repository, it works perfectly fine `git clone git@bitbucket.org:org/B.git`

It seems like repositories that are trying to be cloned via `git submodule update --init` cannot see/use the ssh access key I have added.

[Git Submodule - Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957125/git-submodule-permission-denied) suggestions haven't worked

- *maybe the key needs to be refreshed?* No, the key works perfectly fine for downloading all other repositories
- *maybe there is an issue with the key itself, try `ssh -vT git@github.com`* After changing it to `bitbucket.org` it works perfectly fine, with successful authentication.
- *I didn't have this problem with http :/* - I didn't either and I hate ssh for this, but, alas it's required.

**How can resolve this issue? Or what configuration am I missing?**

I will be doing this in a development docker container environment so it needs to not preclude that.

This is not like the following problems:

- [Git submodules and ssh access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031494/git-submodules-and-ssh-access)
- [git push: permission denied (public key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660744/git-push-permission-denied-public-key)

Comment: Consider using GIT_TRACE and/or whatever system tracing facilities you have, to see if for some reason the submodule clone is using a different ssh implementation than a manual `git clone`. That's the most likely culprit, I think: that you have two different `ssh` commands on your computer, one of which works here and one of which doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - will try it today. I know that PowerShell has aliases things like curl so potentially two different SSH implementations are causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure what key is actually used when cloning your repository.
If your access key is not your default key (default as in ~/.ssh/id_rsa for instance), then the URL of your subrepository needs to be reference that second key (the access key)

You can change the [remote URL of a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/6309):

git submodule set-url --  accessKey:me/mySubmoduleRepository

It will use a `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host accessKey
  hostname bitbucket.or
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myAccessKey
```

That way a `git submodule update --init` will use an SSH URL directly referencing your access key: the submodule should be cloned.

Comment: Yes, the key is the default and only key on my machine, I am not doing anything special when I clone repo A, it correctly fetches the key from the "~/.ssh/id_rsa".

that is a good suggestion but won't it mean that colleagues would need to configure their ssh in the same way? Otherwise, they would have their own permissions issues trying to find a key unspecified.

Comment: @hiimBacon If a direct `git clone git@bitbucket.org:org/B.git` is working, then you do not need a `~/.ssh/config` file. Still, double-check the content of said `~/.ssh/config`, and check also any "`insteadOf`" directive from your global Git config: `git config --global -l|grep -i inseadof`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to clone the submodule using https and not ssh: change from `git@bitbucket.org:` to `https://bitbucket.org/` in the .gitmodule, then

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init
```

See [Git submodule: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248883/git-submodule-gitgithub-com-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-r)

Comment: Unfortunately, I work as part of a team and changing the system over to use HTTPS would likely not be appreciated.

Though I agree this would avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was because the MING terminal does not use the same authentication method as the Sourcetree UI.

Short answer, type this into the terminal before you run `git submodule update --init`

```
git config credential.helper sourcetree
```

I found this answer here:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2029

NOTE:
You must make sure your 'parent' repository is setup to use ssh in Sourcetree. You can check this by clicking *Repository->Repository Settings* and looking at the source path. If this start's "http://" then you need to change it otherwise this answer will not work.
A bit more on this here: [How can I set Sourcetree to use ssh paths by default when cloning a remote repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037455/how-can-i-set-sourcetree-to-use-ssh-paths-by-default-when-cloning-a-remote-repo)